# Finding best stamp place on document without text and image overlapping

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, document

I guess algoritm should consist of followig stemps (example is located at bottom):

1. Information regions detection (words, images).
2. Finding the best nearest to top position for stamp posting without overlapping with element regions, which has been detected at first step (This step can be implemented with Monte-Carlo method).

Also I have following ideas of text and images region detection:

1. Using tesseract or another OCR. Disadvantage of this method is some page elements can not be deteted (lines, pictures and other). Also text recognition is overhead for this task.
2. Using OpenCV or another computer vision libraries (But I don't know how exactly).

Are anybody could advise more better methods, algotithms or libraries for findind best stamp position on document.

[image: Stamp posting sample]

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, yes, stamp and document are printing at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I would go on a naive but a robust solution, assuming that you know the size of the stamp.

Let's assume the document is 1000*1000 pixels, and the stamp is 200*100.
Create pyramids for the document (for example for 4 pyramids down sample it to 500*500, 250*250, 125*125, 67*67).
For the smallest pyramid (which is 16 times smaller then the original image), search for an empty rectangle sized 12*6 when you find such locations, go up in the pyramid and check if it's ok.

It's not the most efficient solution, but it will work pretty fast because of the pyramids.

I think OCR is an overkill for such problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need or want OCR for this.

Assuming white pixels in the original image have value 0 and black have value 1, with shades of grey having intermediate values (if this is not the case then just rescale and/or negate the image as necessary), the "ideal" solution is:

- Set best = infinity
- For every possible top-left position (x, y) for the stamp image:

  - Set s = 0
  - For every non-white (or "non-transparent") pixel (i, j) in the stamp:

    - s += PagePixel(x+i, y+j) (or some other function of the pixel value, see below)
  - If s is lower than best, we have found a better placement:

    - Set best to s, bestX to x and bestY to y

Afterwards, (bestX, bestY) will be the location of the stamp that overwrites the lowest total "weight" of dark pixels.  You may prefer using squared pixel values, or some other function, to give more importance to avoiding very dark pixels.

Because the above procedure needs time proportional to the number of pixels in the page multiplied by the number of non-white pixels in the stamp, it might be slow (it should still take only a fraction of a second on any modern CPU).  In that case, it would make sense to subsample both images, as suggested by [OopsUser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13847236/47984).